# iTunes match will not upload any unmatched songs

Tags: macos, itunes, icloud, music, data-transfer

I've got a few audio tracks (hypnosis audio CD's which I imported into iTunes) which iTunes can't match and tries to upload. However it iTM gets stuck on stage 3 and never uploads these files.

I have tried converting them in iTunes to AAC format but this doesn't seem work either. It just sits there trying to upload without any error messages.

I've already tried signing out of iTM, iTunes Store and re-enabling. I've also ripped a fresh version of the files from the original CD to make sure the files weren't corrupted. I've also tried uploading other audio files that iTunes can't match and it seems to be any audio. Nothing will upload.

Any suggestions?

OSX 10.9.3
Latest version of iTunes
Macbook Pro late 2013 version

Comment: Could you hit cmd+I on a track to show us the track infos? (the summary tab)

Comment: Hey Kevin. Thanks for your comment. After a back and forth between apple suport it turns out the tracks I had been trying to upload didn't have enough information. Once I added as much track info as possible to each track they eventually uploaded. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

After a back and forth between apple suport it turns out the tracks I had been trying to upload didn't have enough information. Once I added as much track info as possible to each track they eventually uploaded. Hope this helps someone else.